# Spark:RDD created from DataSet has null values

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am trying to create RDD from Dataset as below:

```
 Dataset<Positions> bondDF = SQLContext.sql("select * from 
 df_positions where asset_type='BOND'").as(positionsEncoder);
 bondDF.show();
 JavaRDD<Positions> bondRDD = bondDF.toJavaRDD();
 System.out.println("Bond RDD :"+ bondRDD.first().getAsset_type());
```

`bondDF.show()` output is:

```
|asset_type |book_id |instrument_id |product_category |product_code |  product_name|
+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------------+-------------+--------------+
|BOND       |CBOND_1 |    46637K547 |    FIXED_INCOME |    100      |CORPORATE BOND|
```

RDD output is null but I expect it to be `BOND`. Infact all the attributes like `asset_type`, `book_id` etc are null.

Comment: `show` and `first` might return different `Positions`.

Comment: Currently I have only 1 record. I tried with `collect` too but all the properties in position are null